# How can I conduct find and replace on columns containing dates with general formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, date, replace

I have been trying to replace all "-" to "/" in my excel spreadsheet with VBA but it is not working the way I want it. Please send help :')

**Issue:** Cells that contain dates in the format of 00-00-0000 are changed to 00.00.0000 instead of the desired 00/00/0000 format. The results are the same even if I do this manually using the Excel find and replace function.

Some information regarding the date cells:

- They are in the "general" format and changes to "Date" format (some still remain as general) after the code runs

**Code:**

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim X, Y As Range

Set X = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

  For Each Y In X.Cells
      Y = Replace(Y, "-", "/")
  Next Y

End Sub
```

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Use `Replace(Y, "-", "/")`?  You are currently replacing dot, not dash.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but the code still does not work even with dash

Comment: You might try to use the [DATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). How are your value arranged? DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY or else?

Comment: can you post some example data?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey. I tried the date function manually but it does not give me the DD/MM/YYYY format that I required either.

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing the data you could try this...

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim x, y As Range

Set x = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

  For Each y In x.Cells
      y = format(y,"dd/mm/yyyy")
  Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code you have suggested but it gave me a Run-time error 6; Overflow error. x.x The data is simply some numbers in DD/MM/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM and in general format. If I am not wrong, some know these data as dates formatted in text? However, even when i tried finding and replacing the dates in date format with the above code, it still did not work.

Comment: The second y in the formula is lowercase. Try to change it to uppercase.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Yes, you are right, I've changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data are also in the format DD.MM.YYYY, i've written this subroutine:

```
Sub FindReplace()

    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    
    Set RngRange01 = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01
        RngTarget.Value = DateSerial(Right(RngTarget.Value, 4), Mid(RngTarget.Value, 4, 2), Left(RngTarget.Value, 2))
    Next RngTarget

End Sub
```

I've tested it on a range with dates written with the point instead of the slash and it seems to work for me.

An extra tip: i'd not use a single letter to identify a variable. It is really hard to replace them and to track them. At least 3 letters that you usually do not find in the rest of the code are way better. Something like `xyz` or `sss` or `qwe`. Even better if you add a little tag to remember you what kind of variables they are (like `Rng` for range or `Byt` for byte or `Dbl` for double).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me either as the issue laid with my Regional and Language settings. I only had to change my format to English (UK) and the issue would be gone~ Thank you for your answer and tips though!!

Comment: What language/regional settings do you have? Does the subroutine return any error? Does it give you any result?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @EvilBlueMonkey , my language/regional settings was in French (Switzerland). Yes it did. I received a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

Comment: Hm, i'd say it is trying to covert a data that is not supposed to be a date. You can either try to define your range better not including anything but dates or try to put a `On Error Resume Next` before the For-Next cycle. I'd suggest the first.